# How can I intersect a Line2D with a Area in Java?

Tags: java, geometry, line, shapes

I have a Line2D and a Area object and I want the intersecting Line2D. The result can be also a GeneralPath. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [instersects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersects%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) in class Area. Line2D could be replaced by a Rectangle2D though.

Comment: ? How would that work? I can think of a bunch of examples where it doesn't work..

Comment: Create a rectangle2d with the same dimension as your Line2D. Create your area, call intersects with the rectanlg2d.

Comment: Example: What about a rotated line?

Comment: This method return only a boolean. If you means then intersect(Area rhs) then you receive a Area. But this is a area and not a line or a path. But I need a start and end point of the line.

Comment: Ohhh.. So your gonna have some fun with linear interpolation. s your area square at least ?

Comment: In the most cases the Area object are rectangles but it can also circle or ellipses.

Comment: look at my second answer, it's generic

Answer (score 0):

Second chance :

- build your line2D, it is a shape.
- Build an area around it (using new Area( line2d ) );
- take the first area and call [intersect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersect%28java.awt.geom.Area%29) with the second area obtained from the line.
- your first area is now the intersection of the first.
- take your leftmost, topmost, bottomost, rightmost coordinates
- turn them into a line2d

and here you are.

Comment: new Area( line2d ) create an empty Area. But your answer give me some hints. I will test it.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing the answer if you got it

Comment: i try to find the new Area constructor in java api. where is it? there is no constructor like that!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, approximate the Line2D by triangles:

```java
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(new int[]{x1, x2, x2}, new int[]{y1, y2+e, y2-e}, 3);
    Area triangle = new Area(polygon);
    triangle.intersect(area); // intersection of ray and area
    return !triangle.isEmpty(); // returns true if intersects
```

Option 2, use the Geometry class instead

```java
  private final GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
  private ShapeReader shapeReader = new ShapeReader(geometryFactory);

  Path2D.Double thePath = new Path2D.Double(area);
  Geometry geometry  = shapeReader.read(thePath.getPathIterator(null));

  Coordinate[] coordinate = new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(x1, y1), new Coordinate(x2, y2)};
  LineString centerRay = geometryFactory.createLineString(coordinate);

  return geometry.intersects(centerRay); // returns true if intersects
```